# How can I insert multiple records into a specific row's repeated record field in BigQuery?

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a very simple BigQuery table schema:

```
Field name          Type        Mode

thing               STRING      NULLABLE    
arraything          RECORD      REPEATED    
    quotekey        STRING      NULLABLE    
    policyvalue     INTEGER     NULLABLE    
    testbool        BOOLEAN     NULLABLE    
    testtimestamp   TIMESTAMP   NULLABLE
```

I inserted a row with just a `thing`:

```
INSERT INTO `...tablename`(thing) VALUES('Moose');
```

I need to be able to insert multiple objects into my `arraything` and from what I can gather the syntax for that is:

```
UPDATE `...tablename` SET arraything = ARRAY_CONCAT(arraything, [("a string", 6, true, NULL)]) WHERE thing = 'Moose';
```

However, I get the error:

```
Query error: No matching signature for function ARRAY_CONCAT for argument types: ARRAY<STRUCT<quotekey STRING, policyvalue INT64, testbool BOOL, ...>>, ARRAY<STRUCT<STRING, INT64, BOOL, ...>>. Supported signature: ARRAY_CONCAT(ARRAY, [ARRAY, ...]) at [36:78]
```

Is it not possible to use `ARRAY_CONCAT` with a repeated type?  How would achieve inserting (multiple though one at a time for now) `arraything`s into a row where `thing` = 'Moose'?  Do I need to do some casting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider below fixed syntax

```
UPDATE `...tablename`
SET arraything = ARRAY_CONCAT(
  arraything, [
    struct<quotekey STRING, policyvalue INTEGER, testbool BOOLEAN, testtimestamp TIMESTAMP>
    ("a string", 6, true, NULL)
  ]
) 
WHERE thing = 'Moose';
```