# How can I insert data into this structure in BigQuery?

Tags: google-bigquery

In BigQuery, I want to insert some data into this very simple data structure:

```
Field             Type     Mode

id                STRING   NULLABLE
policies          RECORD   REPEATED
 s                RECORD   NULLABLE
  something       STRING   NULLABLE
  riskTypes       RECORD   REPEATED
   code           STRING   NULLABLE
```

In the light of my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69191440/how-can-i-insert-multiple-records-into-a-specific-rows-repeated-record-field-in) I would expect the syntax to be as follows:

```
UPDATE `tablename` SET policies = ARRAY_CONCAT(
policies, [
    struct<s  struct<something STRING, riskTypes ARRAY<struct<code STRING>>>
    ("example something", [("example description")])
]
) 
WHERE id = 'Moose';
```

But this gives an error:

`Unexpected "["` (before the "example description")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below should work

```
update `tablename` set policies = policies ||  [
  struct<s struct<something string, riskTypes array<struct<code string>> >>
    (struct('example something' as something, [struct('example description 1' as code), struct('example description 2')]))  
]
where id = 'Moose'
```

Comment: What is `data` here please.

Comment: sorry, that was left-overs from quick test I did